# How to deal with __vite-browser-external errors ("debuglog" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external")

Tags: node.js, vite, console.log, rollupjs

I am currently using Vite in conjunction with react to build a site.
I have an open source logging library called [Winston.](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) that I am using in 'development'. Initially Winston was built for NodeJs, but in version 3, they enabled support for logging to web applications.

The installation of this was not straightforward and I came across an article written by Kyle Kravette called [How to Use Winston in Vite](https://dev.to/kjk93/how-to-use-winston-in-vite-3fdj) which does an outstanding job in describing the process of installation.

So to clarify I am able to use Winston in development and it works has expected, however the pain-point comes when I try to build the app running `npm run build` I come accross the following error.

```
vite v4.1.4 building for production...
✓ 403 modules transformed.
"debuglog" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/readable.js".
4: Readable.ReadableState = ReadableState;
5: import EventEmitter from 'events';
6: import {inherits, debuglog} from 'util';
                     ^
7: import BufferList from './buffer-list';
8: import {StringDecoder} from 'string_decoder';
error during build:
RollupError: "debuglog" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/readable.js".
at error (file:///Users/***/Projects/dashboard/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2095:30)
```

I understand in general terms the feature of the polyfill plugins that are used to polyfill the NodeJs functions that Winston is looking for. But it seems to me that there is not one for this particular module `debuglog`.

I was wondering if there are any users out there who have encountered the same problem.
I have looked on numerous GitHub issue posts and forums but have been unsuccessful in coming up with any answers

I would appreciate any advice or insights that you may have in regards to a solution to this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue but I'm building a library not site.
In case it's helpful, someone posted a potential solution on dev.to

> The solution is put some script on `index.html`
>
> ^^^ [*"Teerasak Vichadee" - dev.to*](https://dev.to/ilumin/vite-build-failed-on-project-with-aws-sdk-14dk)

```js
<script>
var global = global || window
var Buffer = Buffer || []
var process = process || { env: { DEBUG: undefined }, version: [] }
</script>
```

^^^ in their case the error was

```bash
'request' is not exported by __vite-browser-external, imported by node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist/es/remoteProvider/httpRequest.js
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this does not work in my situation.